# Python 3 - Google Drive API: AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'children'

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I made a command-line folder selector. I want it to list all files in the folder. I've tried by using the service.children()-thing but I can't get that to work.
The thing that doesn't work:

```
files = service.children().list(folderId=file_id).execute()
```

Here is the code instancing `service` object:

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

Other parts of the code works, so I know that the service is working

I know that the variable `file_id` is a valid folder.
Someone who knows that it might be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you have recently upgraded your API version from 2 to 3! Per the [Drive API changelog](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/migration), there is no `children()` resource anymore. I suspect there are other changes you aren't expecting, so be sure to review that changelog.

Some helpful info via the Python Client Library documentation for [Drive V3](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/):

> `about()` Returns the about Resource.
> `changes()` Returns the changes Resource.
> `channels()` Returns the channels Resource.
> `comments()` Returns the comments Resource.
> `files()` Returns the files Resource.
> `permissions()` Returns the permissions Resource.
> `replies()` Returns the replies Resource.
> `revisions()` Returns the revisions Resource.
> `teamdrives()` Returns the teamdrives Resource.
> `new_batch_http_request()` Create a `BatchHttpRequest` object based on the discovery document.

If you don't want to migrate, there is still a `children()` resource for [Drive V2](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/python/latest/):

> `about()` Returns the about Resource.
> `apps()` Returns the apps Resource.
> `changes()` Returns the changes Resource.
> `channels()` Returns the channels Resource.
> `children()` Returns the children Resource.
> `comments()` Returns the comments Resource.
> `files()` Returns the files Resource.
> `parents()` Returns the parents Resource.
> `permissions()` Returns the permissions Resource.
> `properties()` Returns the properties Resource.
> `realtime()` Returns the realtime Resource.
> `replies()` Returns the replies Resource.
> `revisions()` Returns the revisions Resource.
> `teamdrives()` Returns the teamdrives Resource.
> `new_batch_http_request()` Create a `BatchHttpRequest` object based on the discovery document.

Your solution, then, is to either build the V2 version of the Drive REST API:

```
service = build('drive', 'v2', ...)
```

or continue using `v3` and update your code to use the `files()` resource as is now required.

You can request the children of a folder having id `folderId` with the proper arguments and calling `list` and `list_next`:

Python3 code:

```
kwargs = {
  "q": "'{}' in parents".format(folderId),
  # Specify what you want in the response as a best practice. This string
  # will only get the files' ids, names, and the ids of any folders that they are in
  "fields": "nextPageToken,incompleteSearch,files(id,parents,name)",
  # Add any other arguments to pass to list()
}
request = service.files().list(**kwargs)
while request is not None:
  response = request.execute()
  # Do stuff with response['files']
  request = service.files().list_next(request, response)
```

References:

- [Querystring parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters)
- [PyDoc, v3](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/index.html)
- [PyDoc, v2](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/python/latest/index.html)
- ["fields" and Partial Responses](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance#partial)

Comment: In my case I had to use "'{}' in parents" (check ' ' around {}).

Comment: As per [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#query_string_examples), the `folderId` must be in quotes